# with_credentials=true contradicts Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, cors, credentials

Assume I have cookie based authentication on my site.

So once user authenticated he receives cookie (say `session_id`).

Now I am developing google chrome extension which might be opened on **any** site and the extension calls to my API.

I need that the auth cookie will be sent along with requests to my domain so I'm calling axios (or fetch or whatever) with `{ with_credentials: true }` however it implies that I can't use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` but thats exactly what I need because I am indeed accepting any origin.

What should I do?

Comment: If you accept credentialed requests from any origin, you expose your users to cross-site request forgery attacks.